# git - continuing after a fatal message

Tags: git

After resolving a merge conflicts I haved added files to the staging area. Then I have accidentally executed a commit command with the amend option:

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

I have got the following message:

```
fatal: You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend.
```

Does it mean that the commit command has not been executed at all ? Can I just continue with the correct command ? :

```
git commit --no-edit
```

Comment: You could simply look at your commit history and find out. Either with `git log` or better with `tig`.

Comment: `git log` and `git reflog` show only successful merge commit, so everything looks fine. Does it mean that git commands which return a fatal error can be treated as not executed at all ?

Comment: The error message says that it cannot amend the current commit, therefore the command was not executed. The message has been displayed by a validation that happens before the actual processing starts. Run the correct command without fear.

Comment: You can try `git merge --continue` , and then do the commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message [*"You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend."*](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.29.2/builtin/commit.c#L1183) is generated by the function [`parse_and_validate_options()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.29.2/builtin/commit.c#L1155-L1242) that is [called by the function `cmd_commit()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.29.2/builtin/commit.c#L1580) **before** it starts [the actual work](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.29.2/builtin/commit.c#L1588).

The relevant part of the code of the `commit` command looks [starts like this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.29.2/builtin/commit.c#L1564-L1597):

```c
    ...
    if (argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-h"))
        usage_with_options(builtin_commit_usage, builtin_commit_options);

    status_init_config(&s, git_commit_config);
    s.commit_template = 1;
    status_format = STATUS_FORMAT_NONE; /* Ignore status.short */
    s.colopts = 0;

    if (get_oid("HEAD", &oid))
        current_head = NULL;
    else {
        current_head = lookup_commit_or_die(&oid, "HEAD");
        if (parse_commit(current_head))
            die(_("could not parse HEAD commit"));
    }
    verbose = -1; /* unspecified */
    argc = parse_and_validate_options(argc, argv, builtin_commit_options,
                      builtin_commit_usage,
                      prefix, current_head, &s);
    if (verbose == -1)
        verbose = (config_commit_verbose < 0) ? 0 : config_commit_verbose;

    if (dry_run)
        return dry_run_commit(argv, prefix, current_head, &s);
    index_file = prepare_index(argv, prefix, current_head, 0);

    /* Set up everything for writing the commit object.  This includes
       running hooks, writing the trees, and interacting with the user.  */
    if (!prepare_to_commit(index_file, prefix,
                   current_head, &s, &author_ident)) {
        rollback_index_files();
        return 1;
    }

    ...
```

Before the line `index_file = prepare_index(argv, prefix, current_head, 0)` the code does not change anything, it validates the command line arguments and identifies the needed objects (the current commit).

The command you have run by mistake didn't change anything in the repository. The safety measures implemented in Git prevented it to break your work. You can safely run the correct command to conclude the merge.